# can anyone explain why this code regarding plotly libraries worked well in jupyter notebook but showed an error when i ran it in intellij

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I saw this video on youtube : using plotting a dataframe using iplot method imported from plotly.offline module.

I ran this code on intellij but got an error saying :
latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(256)

i looked up for a solution but couldn't anything. Then i ran this code in jupyter notebook and it worked just fine

can anyone explain this.

source code -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import chart_studio.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import *
import cufflinks as cf


init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline() 

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df.iplot()
```

Comment: Did you run it as a file (python script.py) in IntelliJ?
If so, then I would recommend checking if running with the same interpreter from the system terminal produces the same erorr.

Comment: @SergeyK. intellij created a .py file. Are you recommending to run the file using the local terminal ?

Comment: Yes, either run it in the built-in terminal or the system one (make sure you use the same interpreter). If the same error appears, then it's something related to the interpreter itself and not IntelliJ.

Comment: I ran it in both, it gives the same error

Comment: Then it's something with the interpreter. Try creating a new virtualenv, it may help.
You can also configure in IntelliJ the same interpreter that you use for the jupyter notebook. To find out which one is used, run `import sys` `print(sys.executable)` in a jupyter notebook cell.
After that, configure that interpreter in IntelliJ. It should work.